# How to find a row in a QStandardItemModel

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QStandardItemModel with 8 columns. I'm looking for a way to get the  number of the row containing a specific word in the first column to update it.

I can made a `for` loop to scan all rows, but I think it's the worst thing to do, concerning the performances.

Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Except if you save/update the words or statistics elsewhere each time one is put/modified in a cell I don't see how you can without the loop. Do you have a so huge number of row ?

Comment: I think you would need a map or similar to catalog what words are in what rows to save having to loop each time.

Comment: @bruno Great idea, thank you! I do not know why I did not think about it before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `QMap<QString, int>` with QString = the word to search and int = the row where it's stored.

Thanks @bruno @drescherjm

Comment: if a word can be used on several rows the _int_ must be a QList etc or the _int_ is just the number of times the word appears, depending on what you need

Comment: Yeah, it's not my case, personnally. To avoid that, we should check firstly that the keyword doesn't exist. If it exists, we could add `.1` ; `.2`, ... at the end, and check all lines when we want to look for this word.

Comment: @bruno `QMap` is multimap, ie. one key can have many values (and ´QMultiMap` makes it more explicit and convenient). No need for an explicit list.